# How to get landmass polygons for bounding box in Overpass API?

Tags: overpass-api

Can anyone show me how to get area polygons (just any landmass) with bounding box using Overpass?

I just want to differentiate between water and land - if you think it's better to assume everywhere is dry land and query for polygons of water to specifically render them instead, then please demonstrate this if possible.

EDIT: To clarify, I can't do massive queries (I'm splitting them up into bounding boxes), so I'm really pleased with the **relation"type"="boundary";** solution, but I just need to tailor that query to filter out or ignore bodies of water. There must be a query that just returns useful "land only" polygons for a specific bounding box.

Comment: Are you looking for continents/oceans polygons?

Comment: I'm looking for any water polygons at all within the bounding box, so I can render them as filled polygons to distinguish everything else as solid land.

Comment: Similar to this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297811/how-can-i-remove-water-from-openstreetmap-ways I just want the simplest way to distinguish land from water, via an Overpass query. I don't particularly mind whether it's the land or the water polygon(s) that I get.

Comment: In such case, try MDHald's solution with overpass-turbo.eu API.

Comment: I'm trying, but one solution only gives me a line boundary of the coast (where I actually need a full polygon), and the other gives me polygons that don't care if they encompass water or not.

Comment: For coastline - you need big shapes. You may take them here http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Coastline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Overpass Turbo

To get Admin Boundaries use the [`Boundary` tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative)

```
[out:json];

(
  relation["type"="boundary"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

To get the Water use the [`Water` Tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dwater) For the water tag add whatever you need in terms of specific water types. The code is below.

```
[out:json];

(

  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  way["water"="lake"]({{bbox}});
  way["natural"="coastline"]({{bbox}});
  way["waterway"="riverbank"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Rivers are also modeled using relations, i.e. you'll have to add them to your query for a complete response. The boundary tag query returns all sorts of boundaries, not only admin boundaries.

Comment: This boundary query seemed perfect at first, but then I noticed it doesn't "rule out" bodies of water (eg. draws a polygon including Birkenhead and Liverpool, encompassing the River Mersey). Can this be tweaked to exclude water?

How can I get river data from relations?

Comment: I believe you would need to do a clip of some sort with the data using a GIS. As I understand the Administrative boundaries are deployed based on the Geo-Political Boundaries and thus would not follow any natural features. 

your best bet is to take the data into a GIS and perform a clip on the Admin boundaries using the River.

Comment: You can always just download the data from [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/)
where you can download the [Cultural Data (Boundaries)](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/) and the [Physical Vectors(Oceans, Lakes, etc)](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/)